# Trying to create a specific style of jquery based menu, unsure how to implement

Tags: jquery, user-interface, menu

My problem here is that I don't have the vocab to search for examples of this style of menu to learn how to achieve it. If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it!

I am trying to create a  fixed header menu, with a set of panels which use images to represents different sections of a lengthy web page (navigation would all be on one page, but within that page).

There would be about 12 or thirteen different images, so I need to be able to scroll back and forward horizontally between the thumnails of the various parts of the page.

I have drawn a concept sketch here:

[image: Page concept]

You can see in my example I have one graph displayed, but many others above and below it on the page, and a highlighted square to sit over the user's current position (or at least last selection, to keep things somewhat simple).

I'm **not** asking you guys to code this for me! But when I search for things like "jquery sliding bar menu", or "jquery thumbnail menu" I'm hitting dead ends, but I am SURE this is the kind of thing jquery would be great at. I'm pretty new to javascript, and mainly just re purpose existing scripts, so any advice for how I could reach this would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for a `carousel`: [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html)

Then, add a click event to the carousel items which would load/show the respective graphs/images on the container below it.

Comment: Ah fantastic! That's exactly it, great, I can get to work right away - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by kayen carousel would be the best searching key for you.

I have similar problem and I have used the responsive carousel for that. It also have the thumnail that would tell on which image you are at.

http://johnpolacek.github.com/ResponsiveThumbnailGallery/